# Extract RSS/ATOM URLs from HTML LINK tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to extract RSS/ATOM URLs from HTML LINK tags? I know regex is not the best way to do this, so I'm wondering what alternatives I have. Surely some kind of horrible string munging using .Contains after loading the HTML into a string is not optimal either. Anyone got a decent strategy for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XPath.

```
1. Convert an HTML into an XHTML with Tidy
2. With the XHTML, use XPath to search for the link
    /html/head/link[@type='application/rss+xml']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=272) can help you. Have not use it. But hear good thing about it.